# How can I access subfolders in iCloud Notes?

Tags: icloud, folders, notes.app

Hello I'm Korean iPhone user and I use Windows notebooks. Previously, I was able to see my Notes and subfolders all expanded, like this:

[image: My notes' folder structure]

However, on the Windows notebook it only shows the most top positioned folder without the subfolders, like this:

[image: folders my window icloud showing]

I can still access the notes on subfolders through the iCloud notes folder, but it is very uncomfortable as it doesn't show me the many subfolder structure.

I would like it to display the folders as it had previously but I can't find a way to change the view setting.  How can get the structure in Windows to display the same way it does on my iPhone?

Comment: Have you checked the settings or preferences?

Comment: What do you mean by "my icloud on window only shows ..." ? Do you mean the contents of your "iCloud Drive" drive as shown by (Windows) Explorer under Windows or as they appear on your iPhone? If on iPhone, which iOS app are you using to view your iCloud folders & files? What's the version of iOS on your iPhone?