# Apple Notes subfolders disappearing in iCloud browser version

Tags: icloud, notes.app

First question to the forum. Thanks ahead of time for any assistance.

I believe I saw one other question asked about this same issue recently, but I felt it wasn't properly explained by the original poster so thought I'd start a new thread here. Hope this is allowed.

**The short version is that the subfolders from my Notes no longer display in the iCloud browser version of Notes.** The subfolders show in the app on my iPhone 8 and MacBook Pro, but do not appear within the browser version. To clarify, this happens on both my MacBook Pro and Windows 10 desktop, so it seems to be a problem with the browser version, not specific to Windows. The problem seems to have aligned with the latest iOS 15 update (currently 15.2), though I can't confirm this is the cause.

I use an iPhone 8 and sync my Notes through iCloud to use on my Windows 10 desktop. As the only available way to sync Notes from Mac to Windows, I login to iCloud through my browser (typically Chrome) to access my synced Notes. All of my Notes are synced, the only thing that has changed is that the subfolders in the index bar on the left are no longer present. This means the only way to navigate to subfolders and the notes within them is by scrolling through the "All iCloud" folder.

For obvious reasons, this makes organizing and using my Notes quite onerous on my desktop. I haven't been able to find a fix, and any info or advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Can you link the other question?

Comment: Ah, it's https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434079/icloud-notes-on-window-i-cant-see-subfolders. These questions are basically the same as far as I can see. If you think the original one lacks crucial detail, please edit it there directly. That's better than having two similar questions looking for answers.